# How can Firebase be used for WebRTC signalling?

Tags: json, firebase, webrtc

I've achieved a successful WebRTC connection using Firebase - but it only works if both users are on the same local network. I've tried using using different STUN servers, and even used TURN, but with the same result.

Is there any sample code or any place which shows how to achieve basic signalling for WebRTC using Firebase? I've tried looking at the docs, and there doesn't seem to be. What confuses me more is that my app works in the local network, but not outside of it.

Btw, I've also used PubNub and I've no problem using that to achieve signalling (even across networks).

I've set up a reference to my data like this

```
myDataRef = new Firebase('https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com');
myDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
var json = snapshot.val();
```

and I communicate messages like so:

```
myDataRef.set(json);
```

The json message will include the action type (candidate, or offer or answer) and will also include the SDP, if required.

Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you read this [google group chat](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/ihy6rE0s5lM/JEG4CAqZl7EJ). They seem to reference using it just fine. I believe you are not handling the ICE candidate exchanges(ice trickling). You can exchange SDPs all day but if you do not allow ICE candidates to be exchanged through signalling as well, then connections across networks are not possible.

Comment: Did you go through this article https://websitebeaver.com/insanely-simple-webrtc-video-chat-using-firebase-with-codepen-demo