# Signalling channel for WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I want to create my own video chat application. I use the WebRTC framework. I read a few tutorials and each of theme assumes that signalling channel exists. How to implement my own signalling channel?

Answer (score 1):

Since signalling is not defined for the WebRTC standard at the moment, it leaves you a few options. Check out this article for more info the following articles:

- [Signalling Options for WebRTC Applications](https://webrtchacks.com/signalling-options-for-webrtc-applications/)
- [Choosing your signalling protocol](https://bloggeek.me/siganling-protocol-webrtc/)

**1.SIP over WebSockets**

Companies like JSSIP offer a SIP signalling framework over Javascript. The advantage here is that it's interoperable with the usual VoIP structures.

- [JSSIP](http://jssip.net/)
- [SIPJS](http://sipjs.com)
- [SIPML5](http://sipml5.org/)

**2.The WebRTC Data Channel**

Uncharted territory but viable!

- Tutorial by [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/webrtc_chat)

**3.XMPP**

If you take this route, it is probably either because you have an existing XMPP installation

- [Jingle](http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/technology-overview/jingle/)

**4.JSON over COMET or WebSockets**

My favourite! WebRTC signalling shouldn't be done any other way than the Web way.

- [Matrix](http://matrix.org/)
- [Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294963/how-can-firebase-be-used-for-webrtc-signalling)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Node.js WebSocket server or other WebSocket server to broker the connection. [Here](http://hawkee.com/snippet/16051/) is a simple guide that gets the first client talking to the server. An alternative is [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/), which can handle the signaling and alleviate most of the complexity of setting up the WebRTC call.

Answer (score 0):

With serverless options available, vanilla HTTP AJAX options may not be bad for scalability and costs.

Create a plain HTTP(s) API exchanging information using JSON.